# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un menú desplegable con hover que vaya hacia arriba?

Tags: html, css

Hola muy buenas a todos.

Por más que le doy vueltas no consigo hacer un menú desplegable en el que las opciones se desplieguen por encima del título.

Digamos que tengo una lista de frutas. Pone frutas, y al pasar el ratón por encima, se despliegan las frutas que tengo, todo esto hecho con hover. Además, hay un alto definido en píxeles, ya que hay más de 12 frutas y quiero poder hacer scroll.
Bueno pues mi duda es cómo podría hacer que se desplegasen las frutas hacia arriba, quedando el título en el mismo sitio. Lo que ocurre ahora mismo es que las frutas van para abajo y el título sube.

Estoy haciéndolo todo sin JS, solamente html y css.

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo, ¡Saludos!

PD: lo de frutas es un ejemplo.

```css
.container-div {
     width: 40%;
     height: 700px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     border: 2px solid #fd8c8c;
}
 .container-div--flex-end {
     align-self: flex-end;
     border: 2px solid green;
}
 .c-ul {
     width: 220px;
     margin: 10px auto;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
     font-size: 18px;
     text-align: center;
}
 .c-ul__title {
     list-style: none;
}
 .c-ul__title:hover .c-ul--list {
     max-height: 1000px;
     transition: 0.3s all ease-in;
}
 .c-ul__a {
     display: block;
     padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
     background: #333;
     color: #eee;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
     border-top: 1px solid #666;
     text-decoration: none;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .c-ul--list {
     width: 220px;
     max-height: 0;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: 0.3s all ease-in;
}
 .c-ul--list-overflow {
     height: 200px;
     overflow: auto;
}
 .c-ul--list__item {
     display: block;
     padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
     background: #333;
     color: #eee;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
     border-top: 1px solid #666;
     text-decoration: none;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .c-ul--list__item:hover {
     background: #666;
     color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div className="container-div">
  <div className="container-div--flex-end">
    <ul className="c-ul">
      <li className="c-ul__title">
        <a className="c-ul__a" href="#">
          Title
        </a>

        <ul className="c-ul--list">
          <div className="c-ul--list-overflow">
            <li>
              <a className="c-ul--list__item" href="URL11">
                Item 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="c-ul--list__item" href="URL12">
                Item 2
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="c-ul--list__item" href="URL11">
                Item 3
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="c-ul--list__item" href="URL12">
                Item 4
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="c-ul--list__item" href="URL11">
                Item 5
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="c-ul--list__item" href="URL11">
                Item 6
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="c-ul--list__item" href="URL11">
                Item 7
              </a>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Puedes compartir tu código?

Comment: Ya está, edité el mensaje principal con el código.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un `transform`, esta propiedad tiene que tener los prefijos como

- `-webkit-` => Safari
- `-moz-` => Firefox
- `-o-` => Opera

Y también `transition` para animar el `transform`

```css
.hovMenuUl {
  position:absolute;
  transform:scale(1,0);
  -webkit-transform:scale(1,0);
  -moz-transform:scale(1,0);
  -o-transform:scale(1,0);
  transform-origin:top center;
  -webkit-transform-origin:top center;
  -moz-transform-origin:top center;
  -o-transform-origin:top center;
  background:#121212;
  color:#fff;
  transition:0.3s;
  -webkit-transition:0.3s;
  -moz-transition:0.3s;
  -o-transition:0.3s;
}

.hovMenuUl > li {
  padding:1rem;
}

.hovMenu:hover + ul {
  transform:scale(1,1);
  -webkit-transform:scale(1,1);
  -moz-transform:scale(1,1);
  -o-transform:scale(1,1);
}

ul:first-child {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p class="hovMenu">List</p>
    <ul class="hovMenuUl">
      <li><p>Subitem</p></li>
      <li><p>Subitem</p></li>
      <li><p>Subitem</p></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

El valor `scale()` escala un elemento en el *Eje X e Y*, si  pruebas con valores inferiores a 1, verás como se hace más angosto cada vez.

Y el `transform-origin` es para posicionar el elemento donde queremos, sin que se vaya tan lejos del `<p>` que debe hacer *hover*

Usé un `float:left` para prevenir que el `<ul>` ocupe toda la pantalla

---

Puede haber casos en los que un elemento superpone al otro

No hay que preocuparse mucho por este problema, pues se soluciona fácilmente con un `z-index`

> Superpondrá a otro elemento si tiene posición relativa y no hay un z-index en alguno de ellos

Por que tenemos lo siguiente

```css
.relative {
  position:relative;
  background:blue;
  height:500px;
  padding:1rem;
}

.absolute {
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<span class="absolute">Absolute</span>
<div class="relative">Relative</div>
```

Como se pude ver, uno superpone a otro, esto altera cuando se cambia el orden de los elementos

```css
.relative {
  position:relative;
  background:blue;
  height:500px;
  padding:1rem;
}

.absolute {
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">Relative</div>
<span class="absolute">Absolute</span>
```

O también podemos superponerlo con un `z-index`

```css
.relative {
  position:relative;
  background:blue;
  height:500px;
  padding:1rem;
}

.absolute {
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<span class="absolute">Absolute</span>
<div class="relative">Relative</div>
```

La propiedad `z-index` pone el orden de los elementos, por defecto todos tienen *0*, a menos que se le ponga esta propiedad.

Si un elemento tiene menor `z-index` que otro, el que tenga mayor `z-index` será superpuesto encima del otro.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, no sabía que tenía esas opciones. Voy a investigar un poco. Por lo que veo además, podré hacer buenos efectos y animaciones con estas propiedades. ¡Saludos!